# How to consume temporary AWS credentials in spring boot?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis

So I am working on spring boot application from which I am expected to access AWS resources, I know how to access the AWS resources via IAM credentials and STS credentials, I am looking for an example or way to consume following temporary AWS credentials via spring boot application.

1. AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
2. AWS_ACCESS_KEY
3. AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
4. AWS_SESSION_ID

Note: I have tried accessing via BasicSessionCredentials and BasicAWSCredentials but no luck with the same getting error **Unable to execute Http request**

So any reference or example to set all four properties using java would help a lot, thanks!!

Comment: which aws service are you trying to connect with Spring boot application?

Comment: I tried connecting kinesis and s3

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html

default credentials provider chain that looks for credentials in this order:

- Environment Variables - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
- Java System Properties - aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey
- Web Identity Token credentials from the environment or container
- Credential profiles file at the default location (~/.aws/credentials) shared by all AWS SDKs and the AWS CLI
- Credentials delivered through the Amazon EC2 container service
- Instance profile credentials delivered through the Amazon EC2 metadata service

```
@Bean
    public AWSCredentialsProvider amazonAWSCredentialsProvider() {
        
        return DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 amazonS3() {
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
          .standard()
          .withCredentials(amazonAWSCredentialsProvider())
          .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
          .build();
    }
```

Comment: How do I set AWS_SESSION_ID ?

Comment: if you are running it locally can set it up as environment variables you dont need to specifically consume them the DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain will consume you can use that to use in the Service client creation, if you will be running in container then set them as container environment variables for testing. If its container ideally the IAM role should be assumed by the container orchestrator or ec2 on which it will be running.

Comment: Tried setting up as environment variable to run on local environment, ain't working for me